# Mock a database function for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, mocking, xunit

I'm trying to make unit tests for a query. Inside this query I call an database function. This function is a CTE (Common-Table-Expression). For testing purposes I want to mock this CTE.

My question is, how am I mocking this database function in entity-framework-core?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short - You can't. You can only mock function C# related data.

[Testing code that uses EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/)

> It is very important to understand that EF Core is not designed to abstract every aspect of the underlying database system. Instead, EF Core is a common set of patterns and concepts that can be used with any database system.

BUT - Depending on the type of tests you are doing:

> 1. Running queries and updates against the same database system used in production.
> 2. Running queries and updates against some other easier to manage database system.
> 3. Using test doubles or some other mechanism to avoid using a database at all.

You could setup the data (1 or 2 - for the 3rd one it's irrelevant), so that your function returns the proper data. You can always do that on for the 1st choice, but not always for the 2nd (as the easier to manage database, will not always support the same functions).

Maybe with some code and a bit more context, we can help more.